# Activeadmin assets Not Loading Rails 4.2

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Previously I was getting an error that I can't quite remember with Rails 4.2 and Activeadmin. So I changed:

```
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";
```

to:

```
@import "active_admin/mixins.css";
@import "active_admin/base.css";
```

This worked just fine in debug mode... and it got rid of my error... but now the css isn't loading in production mode.

I'm just wondering if there's something I should change in maybe production.rb or in my Capfile (I'm using the latest Capistrano), to reflect this change that I made in the active_admin.css.sss

EDIT:

This is the error I was getting before and why I made the changes I made:

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooookay... So the error I was getting was related to SASS (and I really should've taken a screen shot this time... but oh well...) basically it referred to SASS not being able to process the "&" sign... which meant my version of sass-rails was off.

So first I changed:

```
@import "active_admin/mixins.css";
@import "active_admin/base.css";
```

back to:

```
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";
```

Then I updated to the latest version of sass-rails. (I also had to updated to the latest version of capistrano because after I updated I could no longer deploy.)

That's all I did.  I saw that I had specified specific versions of sass-rails and capistrano. So I commented the versioning out and I updated both and it worked.